# Committing offset for a particular partition of a topic using Acknowledgement in springboot

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

I am using Concurrentmessagelistenercontainer for consuming messages from kafka topic. since the consumer can be assigned multiple partitions from a topic within single consumer group.

```
@Configuration
@EnableKafka
public class KafkaConfig {

    @Bean
    KafkaListenerContainerFactory<ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<Integer, String>>
                        kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<Integer, String> factory =
                                new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
        factory.setConcurrency(3);
        factory.getContainerProperties().setPollTimeout(3000);
        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<Integer, String> consumerFactory() {
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(consumerConfigs());
    }

    @Bean
    public Map<String, Object> consumerConfigs() {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, embeddedKafka.getBrokersAsString());
        ...
        return props;
    }
}
```

I want to commit offset of only particular partition for which processing was successful

```
@KafkaListener(id = "thing2", topicPartitions =
        { @TopicPartition(topic = "topic1", partitions = { "0", "1" }),
          @TopicPartition(topic = "topic2", partitions = "0",
             partitionOffsets = @PartitionOffset(partition = "1", initialOffset = "100"))
        })
public void listen(List<ConsumerRecord<String, String> records, Acknowledgement acknowledgement) {
   Map<TopicPartition, List<ConsumerRecord>> records = ....
     
     acknowledgement.acknowledge();
    ...
}
```

Acknowledgement does not provides option to specify partition for which we needs to commit offset. It will by default  commit offset for all the partitions. Is there any way we can achieve it?

I tried to look into spring kafka documentation
https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/api/org/springframework/kafka/support/Acknowledgment.html

there is no provision of providing partition number for committing the offset.

Answer (score 0):

When you do partition assignment, you don't deal with consumer groups. That's not related to to the problem, just to clarify things a bit.

Now look into the logic of the `ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer`:

```
TopicPartitionOffset[] topicPartitions = containerProperties.getTopicPartitions();
        if (topicPartitions != null && this.concurrency > topicPartitions.length) {
            this.logger.warn(() -> "When specific partitions are provided, the concurrency must be less than or "
                    + "equal to the number of partitions; reduced from " + this.concurrency + " to "
                    + topicPartitions.length);
            this.concurrency = topicPartitions.length;
        }
        setRunning(true);

        for (int i = 0; i < this.concurrency; i++) {
            KafkaMessageListenerContainer<K, V> container =
                    constructContainer(containerProperties, topicPartitions, i);
            configureChildContainer(i, container);
            if (isPaused()) {
                container.pause();
            }
            container.start();
            this.containers.add(container);
        }
```

So, if `concurrency` is big enough (or better equal to the number of partitions), we create a target `KafkaMessageListenerContainer` for the specific partition.
And since all of those `KafkaMessageListenerContainer` instances deal only with a single partition. So, your `listen()` method is going to receive a records batch only from one partition at a time. Therefore it is safe to call that `acknowledgement.acknowledge()` and it will be performed for this batch from a single partition. Your problem is only to configure `concurrency` as big enough to cover all the partition you assign.